# TextView description under ImageView in GridView

Tags: android, gridview

This is my ImageAdapter class:

```
package com.javacodegeeks.android.googlemaps;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;

        if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        return imageView;
    }

    // references to our images
    private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.muze, R.drawable.anit, R.drawable.ibadethane, R.drawable.hepsimenu
    };

    private String[] mThumbTxt = {
            "Müzeler", "Anıtlar", "İbadethaneler", "Hepsi"
    };

}
```

How can i add image descriptions (as in TextView), from mThumbTxt array, under ImageViews without messing with GridView structure?

Answer (score 2):

Have your view be a `TextView` instead of an `ImageView`. Set the image as the top drawable:

```
textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, mThunbIds[position], 0, 0);
textView.setText(mThumbTxt[position]);
```

The only disadvantage here is that the drawables will be drawn at their intrisic size. You can create a ClipDrawable to fix that. Alternatively, make your view a `VerticalLayout` containing an `ImageView` and a `TextView`. It would be simpler, then, to load it from xml.

Answer (score 1):

simple way add an layout for gridView as:

**gridView.xml :**

```
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/relaGrid"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
           <ImageView android:id="@+id/chooseImage"
                       android:src="@drawable/ph1"
                        android:layout_width="85dp"
                        android:layout_height="85dp"
                        >
                        </ImageView>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/chooseText"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_width="85dp"
                      android:text="TextView"
                      android:layout_below="@+id/chooseImage"
                      android:gravity="center"
                      android:singleLine="true"
                      android:ellipsize="marquee"
                      android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
                      ></TextView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I getView method of ImageAdapter :

```
 @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {
View view = View.inflate(mContext, R.layout.relagrid, null);
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.relaGrid);

ImageView image = (ImageView) rl.findViewById(R.id.chooseImage);
TextView text = (TextView) rl.findViewById(R.id.chooseText);       
image.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
text.setText(mThumbTxt[position]);
return rl;
}
```

Comment: You should reuse `convertView` when possible. See [this Google I/O presentation on ListView](http://www.google.com/intl/ko-KR/events/io/2010/sessions/world-of-listview-android.html)